# Is there a c++ counterpart to posix_memalign?

Tags: c++

When I call [`posix_memalign`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html) to allocate aligned memory for an object of type `Foo` in my C++ code, I am required to do a `reinterpret_cast` of the address of that pointer to `void**`.

In general when I encounter this situation, it implies that I am missing some language feature. That is, it feels like I am calling `malloc` in `c++` when I should be calling `new`. 
, 
Is there a type-aware `new` equivalent for aligned memory allocation in `c++`?

Comment: I thought it would be aligned by default (when using new) unless you purposefully made sure it wasn't?

Comment: @Borgleader, I thought so too, but it is not. I checked at runtime with an `assert` on the last 6 bits of the address, which failed.

Comment: Use the `alignas` keyword?

Comment: @KerrekSB, I actually hadn't heard of that. I am trying that now to see if it works with my ancient compiler `g++ 4.4.7` and also passes the assert test.

Comment: @KerrekSB, Unfortunately `g++ 4.4.7` does not support that and my project is currently still tied to this compiler.

Comment: Overload new for `Foo` to use `posix_memalign`?

Comment: Your version of GCC might support alignment extensions that work similarly to the now standardized alignas.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html.

Comment: reinterpret_cast is overkill: `void* p; if (!posix_memalign(&p, al, sz)) return static_cast<T*>(p);` (this is just a simplified version of Yakk's answer, but worth repeating)

Answer (score 5):

I will start with the core advice first.

```
Foo* aligned_foo() {
  void* raw = 0;
  if(posix_memalign(&raw, 8, sizeof(Foo)))
    return 0; // we could throw or somehow communicate the failure instead
  try{
    return new(raw) Foo();
  }catch(...){
    free(raw);
    throw;
  }
}
```

then when you are done with the `Foo* foo`, do a `foo->~Foo(); free(foo);` instead of `delete`.

Note the lack of `reinterpret_cast`s.

---

Here is an attempt to make it generic:

```
// note: stateless.  Deleting a derived with a base without virtual ~base a bad idea:
template<class T>
struct free_then_delete {
  void operator()(T*t)const{
    if(!t)return;
    t->~T();
    free(t);
  };
};
template<class T>
using aligned_ptr=std::unique_ptr<T,free_then_delete<T>>;

// the raw version.  Dangerous, because the `T*` requires special deletion:
template<class T,class...Args>
T* make_aligned_raw_ptr(size_t alignment, Args&&...args) {
  void* raw = 0;
  if(int err = posix_memalign(&raw, alignment, sizeof(T)))
  {
    if (err==ENOMEM)
      throw std::bad_alloc{};
    return 0; // other possibility is bad alignment: not an exception, just an error
  }
  try {
    // returns a T*
    return new(raw) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  } catch(...) { // the constructor threw, so clean up the memory:
    free(raw);
    throw;
  }
}
template<class T,class...Args> // ,class... Args optional
aligned_ptr<T> make_aligned_ptr(size_t alignment=8, Args&&...args){
  T* t = make_aligned_raw_ptr<T>(alignment, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  if (t)
    return aligned_ptr<T>(t);
  else
    return nullptr;
}
```

The `unique_ptr` alias `aligned_ptr` bundles the destroyer along with the pointer -- as this data requires destruction and free, not delete, this makes it clear.  You can still `.release()` the pointer out, but you still have to do the steps.

Comment: @dyp on failure (non-zero return value) we abort and return a still-empty `retval`

Comment: @dyp fixed.  Added `alignment` argument.  I could make the error codes throw, but ... I am lazy.  I guess throwing out of memory makes sense.  ... that would work: and the fact that `aligned_ptr<T>` cannot throw in construction also makes one warm and fuzzy.  I was attempting to enable NRVO, so all paths return `retval`.  The OP indicated they are using some ancient compiler, hence the bevy of "well, you don't have to do this", and `return {};` is less pretty in C++03.

Comment: Not sure where you'd `return {};`. For the first return `return nullptr;` would work, because that ctor is not explicit. The second return cannot use `{}`, because that ctor *is* explicit.

Comment: @dyp I fixed another bug, and inverted the advice -- put the concrete (short) version first, with your `return new(raw) Foo();`  That one is clean enough I almost want to use it as the core of the `unique_ptr` one -- have the `unique_ptr` one just wrap it with a deleter.

Comment: @dyp rewritten.  I think it is cleaner with the `_raw_ptr` and `_ptr` versions.  Now throws on out of memory, like `new`.

Comment: Nice! Why is there a conditional conversion in `make_aligned_ptr`? Wouldn't just `return aligned_ptr<T>(t)` do? Might it be hard to detect an alignment error if you just get a null pointer back?

Comment: Why do you call `free()` on `raw` when it was created with `new`?

Comment: @0x499 it was allocated with `posix_memalign` and constructed with placement `new`.  `posix_memalign` says to use `free`.  I manually destruct to invert placement `new`.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you don't want to do a `reinterpret_cast` because then your `Foo` constructor isn't called.  If you need to allocate memory from a special place, you then call placement new to construct the object in that memory:

```
void* alloc;
posix_memalign(&alloc, 8, sizeof(Foo));
Foo* foo = new (foo) Foo();
```

The only other way (pre C++11) would be overriding the `new` operator for your class.  That works if you have a particular class that always requires this special allocation:

```
class Foo {
    void* operator new(size_t size) {
        void* newobj;
        posix_memalign(&newobj, 8, sizeof(Foo));
        return newobj;
    }
};
```

Then anytime you call `new Foo()` it will invoke this allocator.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new for more information.  Overriding `operator new` and `operator delete` can be done for individual classes or globally.

Comment: I get a compiler error (or maybe promoted warning) if I don't do the `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Also I don't mind at all that the constructor is not called (I already do a placement new later), but I care a great deal about the alignment.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking reinterpret cast in the other direction (to Foo). Indeed, Foo** needs the cast to void**.

Comment: I think this `reinterpret_cast` violates the strict aliasing rule. You could try to avoid that by writing it like: `void* foo_v; posix_memalign(&foo_v, 8, sizeof(Foo)); auto foo = new (foo_v) Foo();`

Comment: If you ever say `std::vector<Foo>`, you'll be in for a surprise :-S

Comment: @KerrekSB I assume the surprise you're referring to is that overriding `operator new` only affects objects allocated with `new` and not placement new (as in the case of `vector`) or stack allocated objects.  That is a limitation for sure.  I was trying to focus on what language features might be available.  I actually like Yakk's answer better.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 has added native language support for alignment declarations and aligned allocation.

You can specify [`alignas(N)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) on your type in C++11 to specify the minimum alignment for new objects, which the default `new` will respect.

Example from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas):

```
struct alignas(16) sse_t { // SSE-safe struct aligned on 16-byte boundaries
    float v[4];
};
```

then you can simply do

```
sse_t *ssevec = new sse_t;
```

For a replacement for `posix_memalign`, you can use [`std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), N>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage), also in C++11.

Comment: AFAIK, the alignas specifier only works for variable declarations (both static/global and local/stack variables). You can specify it either at the declaration site as a qualifier of the declaration's type, or on one of the classes we've used for a declaration.

Comment: This answer is partly wrong! In C++11, `new` does not respect in very case `alignas()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511909/does-the-alignas-specifier-work-with-new