# How to align __m256d inside a struct?

Tags: c++, struct, alignment, sse, avx

Consider the following code:

```
// Thin/POD struct
struct Data {
 __m256d a;
 __m256d b;
};
// Thick base class
class Base {
  // ...
};
// Thick derived class
class Derived : public Base {
  Data data;
  // ...
};
```

Is there a way to ensure that `Derived::data` member is properly aligned for AVX (32 byte alignment)?
Because the derived class has a base, there doesn't seem to be a way for something like `class alignas(32) Derived` and placing `data` as the first member of `Derived`.

`Derived` is currently allocated on the stack only, but it may need heap allocation later too.

UPDATE: The compiler is MSVC++2017 , so C++11/14/17 is (partially) supported.

Comment: As far as I know, alignment constraints are propagated from individual fields to the aggregates that contain them. Therefore, the alignment constraints of an `__m256d` field should be propagated to the `Data` struct, and then again to the `Derived` struct. But you could ensure that the `Data` field is aligned by explicitly annotating it with `alignas(__m256d)` (or, if you don't have C++11 support, whatever the syntax is for the compiler you're using).

Comment: Did you notice any mis-alignment? It is supposed to work automatically, possibly leaving padding space in the middle of the object. Dynamic allocation is another matter, and apparently VC++ does not support "Over-aligned dynamic memory allocation" yet.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, no, I haven't noticed any misalignment yet. But I would like to know about potential bugs too, before they happen. Can you point some link about MSVC++'s (un)support of "Over-aligned dynamic memory allocation"? I can't find it on the internet, except generic http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0035r1.html

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/10/c17-features-in-vs-2017-3/

Comment: Thanks, it's now clear to me. Would someone like to combine these comments into an answer?

Comment: Oops, not everything clear. Isn't it possible to achieve properly aligned dynamic allocations by placing `data` into an `std::aligned_storage`? Like `typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Data), alignof(__m256d)>::type data;` in `Derived` class?

Comment: How is that dynamic? The problem before C++17 is that new returns memory with an alignment that does not depend on the type.

Comment: @MarcGlisse , I understood that `std::aligned_storage` at compile time reserves  more memory than `sizeof(Data)` - something close to `sizeof(Data) + sizeof(__m256d)`. Then at run time it looks at the address of the first byte reserved and uses for storage of `Data` the first subsequent address which is a multiple of `sizeof(__m256d)`.

Comment: I don't think that's done automatically, no.

Answer (score 1):

For objects on the stack, alignment is [properly propagated](https://godbolt.org/g/fp6QjP) from fields to the enclosing data structure.

Furthermore, `alignas` can be [used on data members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788947/where-can-i-use-alignas-in-c11)

```
struct S{};

struct T
{
    char c;
    S alignas(32) s;
};
```

For objects on the heap, alignment [isn't guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511909/does-the-alignas-specifier-work-with-new) automatically prior to C++17.

In C++17 there is several alternatives to allocating aligned memory on the heap.

```
struct alignas(32) S {};

auto s1 = std::aligned_alloc(alignof(S), sizeof(S));

auto s2 = new S; // has the meaning of...
auto s2_ = new (std::align_val_t(alignof(S))) S; 

auto sz = alignof(S) + sizeof(S) - 1;
auto s3 = std::malloc(sz);
std::align(alignof(S), sizeof(S), s3, sz);
```

Reference:
[`aligned_alloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/aligned_alloc)
[`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new)
[`align`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align)

As a personal favor and world peace, please don't use `std::align`.