# Why does the C++ standard allow std::max_align_t and __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__ to be inconsistent?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, std

In Visual Studio, when compiling 64-bit:

- `sizeof(std::max_align_t)` is 8
- `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` is 16

So although `std::max_align_t` indicates that implementations of `new` should return pointers aligned to a multiple of 8 bytes, allocations with an alignment requirement of 16 bytes don't call the `void* operator new (std::size_t count, std::align_val_t);` method but call `void* operator new (std::size_t count);` (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) and expect them to return a pointer aligned on 16 bytes.

So allocating a struct defined like this:

```
struct alignas(16) S {double m_value;};
```

will call the standard operator `new` (without `std::align_val_t` argument) and expect it to be aligned on 16 bytes, while `std::max_align_t` only specifies that it should be aligned on 8 bytes.

This means that when overruling the `new` operators, you are forced to align everything on at least 16 bytes, even if 8 bytes would be sufficient.

- Am I missing something?
- Is this an error in the way Visual Studio implements C++/STL?
- Or is this an error in the C++/STL standard?

Comment: [[basic.align\]/3](http://eel.is/c%2B%2Bdraft/basic.align#3) mentions both of these constants but I'm not sure what it implies regarding how their values relate. Since the standard gives different names to alignments greater than each of those I would presume that there is (intentionally) no guarantee that they are identical. Can't tell you why though.

Comment: It doesn't change the result in this case, but I think you intended `alignof(std::max_align_t)`, not `sizeof(std::max_align_t)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two layers of over-aligned types in C++17: extended and new-extended. `std::max_align_t` defines the largest alignment that is not extended, and `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` defines the largest alignment that is not new-extended.

New-extended alignment, as the name suggests, is about the alignment of things you allocate with `new`.

Basically, the regular `operator new` will return memory suitable for any object up to the new-extended alignment size. Any greater alignment prefers the use of `operator new` overloads that specify the alignment of the type being created. And of course, are conditionally supported just like over-aligned types in general. The same goes for the `operator delete` calls to destroy the memory associated with such types.

What Visual Studio is saying is that the maximum alignment that is not considered over-aligned is 8-byte, but the alignment for memory allocated by `operator new` is 16-byte.

---

> This means that when overruling the `new` operators, you are forced to align everything on at least 16 bytes, even if 8 bytes would be sufficient.

Essentially, yes. There's no way to request that the implementation tell you what alignment is being requested with the raw `operator new/delete` overloads.

Now, you can, on an object-by-object basis, overload that object's `operator new` to invoke the alignment-specific `operator new` directly. But you can't make the compiler do so.

Comment: I corrected a typing error in my question: allocations with an alignment requirement of 16 bytes don't call the void* operator new (std::size_t count, std::align_val_t); (I forgot the align_val_t).  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new explicitly states that the new operator with the std::align_val_t argument is called when 'storage required for a single object whose alignment requirement exceeds __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__'.  So this forces implementations to return pointers aligned on 16 bytes, while std::max_align_t states that it must be 8 bytes (by default).

Comment: @Patrick: "*while std::max_align_t states that it must be 8 bytes.*" It states no such thing. That is simply the maximum size before the type is considered to have extended alignment. It says nothing about the alignment of pointers returned from `operator new`.

Comment: you're right.  Assuming that `std::max_align_t` also says something about the alignment of pointers returned by the `operator new` was wrong of me.  Nevertheless, if `__STDDPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` is 16, it means that a lot of memory is lost if you only need 8 bytes (but the same could be said for 4 bytes of course).

Comment: ok, but why is it this way? Why not have new always return 8 byte alignment as well?

Comment: @JosephGarvin: Because types that require 16-byte alignment existed over a decade before C++'s default `new` provided a mechanism to explicitly request allocations of such alignments. In order to allow users to use such types, Microsoft decided to make their default allocator always return 16-byte-aligned pointers.

Comment: @NicolBolas and then for AVX and AVX2 everybody threw up their hands? Because there are 32-byte requiring instructions and the new alignment is still only 16...

Comment: @JosephGarvin: It is possible to write your own allocator which returns memory of higher alignment. At some point, the default may not be good enough. Microsoft simply thought it was a good idea to make the default bigger than others have. Also, AVX was 2011, and Microsoft wasn't about to change the underlying foundation of their standard allocator like that.

Comment: @JosephGarvin C++ allocation functions (`operator new`) typically call `malloc` internally. If the implementation of `malloc` returns a 16-byte aligned memory block, then the C++ implementation has no possibility to change it. Even when not-over-aligned types require 8-byte alignment at maximum.