# What is the correct usage/syntax for the c++17 alignas() specifier for dynamically allocated arrays of fundamental types?

Tags: c++, c++17, alignment, alignas

This must be a repeat question, but I have not found it after searching for 2 days ...

I'm using MSVC with /std:c17 /std:c++17 and trying to get alignas(64) to work with arrays of doubles. The syntax in the code below is the only one I have found that compiles, but it's not aligning ... typically, the array is unaligned about 75% of the time. I know there are many ways to do this with more complicated syntax, but isn't there a way that "just works" with alignas(), as it would for a structure or class?

```
double* AR;
int count=0, asize=10;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    AR = new double alignas(64)[asize];
    if (((uintptr_t)AR & 63) != 0) count++;
    //if (((uintptr_t)AR % 64) != 0) count++;
    delete[] AR;
}
```

Comment: Is `alignas` supposed to work in `new` expressions like this?

Comment: In c++17 it started working with new ... but perhaps for some strange and unknown reason, it doesn't work with simple arrays of fundamental types?

Comment: "*In c++17 it started working with new*" How do you know this? I don't see anything in the C++17 standard about the behavior of applying `alignas` to the type in a `new` expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While C++17 does have the means for `operator new` to be given an alignment for the memory it allocates, there is no mechanism in C++ to specify the alignment for memory allocated by a `new` expression *outside of* the alignment of the type being allocated. That is, if you perform a `new T` or `new T[]`, the alignment of the allocated pointer will be `alignof(T)`. C++17 added alignment-based `operator new` allocators, which [allows them to support over-aligned types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15512182/734069).

This is fine if you have control over `T` and can specify its alignment at definition time via `alignas`. But if you're using someone else's type or a fundamental type like `double`, you can't change the alignment of those types. So there's no way to directly use a `new` expression to allocate such memory.

You will have to use `::operator new` directly to allocate sufficient memory at the desired alignment, and then use placement-`new` to actually create the objects there. Of course, placement-`new` on *arrays* has a number of issues.

I suspect this compiles only because `alignas` is considered an attribute and it is grammatically legal to shove an attribute before the `[]` in a `new` expression. It isn't intended to actually work, as there is [no statement in the section on `new` expressions that allows it to get the alignment of the allocation from anything other than `alignof(T)`.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.new#14)

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid it was something like that, but I got fooled by the fact that the code compiled with no warnings. I wonder if there is any method that is significantly faster than the only one I truly understand:

char* unalignedAddress = new char[asize * sizeof(double) + 64];
char* alignedAddress = (char*)(((size_t)unalignedAddress + 64 - 1) & (-64));
AR = (double*)alignedAddress;